# Linear Congruence Equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How to find the solutions from this equation:

$16X-8\equiv0\pmod{130}$

$GCD(16,130)=2\;$ and $\;2|0\,$.
So there are $2$ principal solutions

$65$ is one of the solutions, but I can’t find the other one.

Comment: Does the first answer to this question helps? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592852/congruence-equation-problem?rq=1

Comment: All the solutions are $\,x=33+65\lambda\,$ for any $\,\lambda\in\mathbb Z\,.\;$ The principal solutions are $\,33\,$ and $\,98\,.$

Comment: $65$ is not a solution:  $16\times65-8\equiv-8\not\equiv0\bmod130$